# SSRS LocalReport Rendering Very Slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

We have developed reports(RDLC) and trying to generate PDF.
about 10000 records need to be bind to report.
The query is retrieving very fast(Not more than 5 sec).
But when rendering this report it is taking more than 3 minutes. The RDLC doesn't have any grouping.

I have verified a few blogs. where they said that in 4.5 framwork it is slow when compared to 3.5.

https://travis.io/blog/2014/10/27/rdlc-performance-issues-dotnet45/

But is there any other way we can solve this problem

```
renderedBytes = localReport.Render(reportType, 
                                   deviceInfo, 
                                   out mimeType, 
                                   out encoding, 
                                   out fileNameExtension,
                                   out  streams, 
                                   out  warnings);
```

This line of code is taking time.

Comment: which platform you are using? windows from?

Comment: IT is  MVC Framework, Web

Comment: Take a step back - what use is a 10,000 row PDF report? Is someone going to print it out and tick and flick it?

Comment: Its an Annexure for customer annual report. so we need to give the print.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I have tried to develop the same application using Visual Studio 2010, framework 3.5, and the result is really surprising.

The same report(Data) took 25 Seconds to generate PDF.